# SQL update entry that matches a username and has highest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `saved_offers` in my database. What I want to do is find all of the entires that match a username, and within those results, the one that has the highest `date` field.

Here's a simpler example: say we have a table `baseball_players`. I want to find the player who plays for the Yankees with the highest batting average, and update his `description` field to say "has the highest batting average".

I'm not a SQL guru by any means, so I apologize if this is overly easy.

I've tried just about every combination of nested SELECTs and ORDERBY's in my update statement, but so far I'm not able to find a command that works.

Comment: `update ... where batting_average = (select max(batting_average) ... )`

Comment: @climbage that'll return the player in the *league* with the highest batting average. I want the player on the yankees.

Comment: then you just need to put `where team = 'Yankees'` in where the second ellipsis is

Comment: Highest batting average from the Yankees would be `SELECT MAX(batting_average) FROM Table WHERE team = 'Yankees'` To update the player from the Yankees: UPDATE table SET description = '' WHERE team = 'Yankees' AND batting_average = (SELECT MAX(batting_average) FROM table WHERE team = 'Yankees')`. Other things to consider: What if multiple people in the same team have the same highest batting average?

Comment: right, I was just giving you the basic idea

Comment: @hdgarrood it wouldn't be *where* team='Yankees'?

Comment: it would, my bad -- just edited.

Comment: @dash team might not have been a good metaphor. It's really a unique userid. I just wanted to update the last offer made by a given user

Answer (score 1):

```
update t a set x = 1 where
a.user = 1 and a.id =
(select top 1 b.id from t b where b.user = a.user and b.date =
(select max(c.date) from t c where c.user = b.user) order by b.id)
```

if the max date appears in more than one record, only one of them will be updated. useful when you want to break a tie between the top values and don't care which is picked.